# Modificar propiedad de un objeto anidado en json

Tags: json, angular

Hola podrían guiarme con alguna solución tengo un json que tiene un objeto anidado, dentro de este objeto tengo 3 propiedades de las cuales 2 tengo que unir y darle un nombre.

```
var jsonInfo: any[] = [
    {
      info1:"ZZZ",
      info2:"NNN",
      objData: {
        data1: "AAA",
        data2: "BBB",
        data3: "CCC"
      }
    }
];
```

En este código capturo los dos valores del objeto que necesito unir, después los elimino y los guardo en un nuevo nombre de propiedad.

```
var jsonModificado = jsonInfo.map((item: any) => {
      var temp = item.objData.data1+ "-" +item.objData.data2;
      delete item.objData.data1;
      delete item.objData.data2;
      item.data1_data2 = temp;
      return item;
});
console.log(jsonModificado);
```

Al imprimir en consola me muestra de esta manera:

```
data1_data2: "AAA-BBB" 
info1:"ZZZ",
info2:"NNN",
objData: {
  data3: "CCC"
}
```

No comprendo como lograr que el resultado sea así:

```
info1:"ZZZ",
info2:"NNN",
objData: {
    data1_data2: "AAA-BBB"
          data3: "CCC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No comprendo como lograr que el resultado sea así

Para lograr este resultado:

```javascript
{
info1:"ZZZ",
info2:"NNN",
objData: {
   data1_data2: "AAA-BBB",
   data3: "CCC"
   }
}
```

En vez de hacer esto:

```js
var jsonInfo = [{
  info1: "ZZZ",
  info2: "NNN",
  objData: {
    data1: "AAA",
    data2: "BBB",
    data3: "CCC"
  }
}];

var jsonModificado = jsonInfo.map((item) => {
  var temp = item.objData.data1 + "-" + item.objData.data2;
  delete item.objData.data1;
  delete item.objData.data2;
  item.data1_data2 = temp;
  return item;
});
console.log(jsonModificado);
```

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var jsonInfo = [
    {
      info1:"ZZZ",
      info2:"NNN",
      objData: {
        data1: "AAA",
        data2: "BBB",
        data3: "CCC"
      }
    }
];

var jsonModificado = jsonInfo.map((item) => {
      var temp = item.objData.data1+ "-" +item.objData.data2;
      delete item.objData.data1;
      delete item.objData.data2;
      item.objData.data1_data2 = temp; // <- Accede a "objData" dentro de item.
      return item;
});
console.log(jsonModificado);
```

Otra solución podría ser:

```js
var jsonInfo = [
    {
      info1:"ZZZ",
      info2:"NNN",
      objData: {
        data1: "AAA",
        data2: "BBB",
        data3: "CCC"
      }
    }
];

var jsonModificado = jsonInfo.map((item) => {
      let newObjData = {
        data3: item.objData.data3,
        data1_data2: item.objData.data1+ "-" +item.objData.data2
      };
      return {...item, objData: newObjData};

});
console.log(jsonModificado);
```

EDIT:

Agrego otra solución en donde pueden haber mas propiedades "dataN:

```js
var jsonInfo = [
    {
      info1:"ZZZ",
      info2:"NNN",
      objData: {
        data1: "AAA",
        data2: "BBB",
        data3: "CCC",
        data4: "DDD",
        data5: "EEE"
        //dataN...
      }
    }
];

var jsonModificado = jsonInfo.map((item) => {
      let newObjData = {
        ...item.objData,
        data1_data2: item.objData.data1+ "-" +item.objData.data2
      };
      return {...item, objData: newObjData};

});
console.log(jsonModificado);
```

PD:

Con respecto a esto

> Hola podrían guiarme con alguna solución tengo un JSON que tiene un objeto anidado

Cuando dices que tienes un "JSON" con un objeto anidado, en realidad lo que tienes es un objeto javascript, mas precisamente un arreglo de objetos, ya que JSON es un formato de texto.

Comment: Para la otra solución que proporcionaste en esta parte              
      let newObjData = {
        data3: item.objData.data3,
        data1_data2: item.objData.data1+ "-" +item.objData.data2
      };                                                                                                                               Si el objeto tuviera muchos datos data3,data4,data5...data40,etc como podría lograr que sea dinámico para no tener que ingresar todas las propiedades manualmente y solo cambiar lo que es data1_data2

Comment: En ese caso deberias optar por la primer solución. A menos que no te interese que sigan estando las propiedades data1 y data2 en el objeto. Si es así dímelo y agrego ese caso en la respuesta

Comment: Me interesó tu segunda solución pero tenía esa inquietud de que si tuviera muchos datos el objeto, lograr el mismo resultado que la primera solución pero usando la segunda solución suponiendo que tuviera muchos datos el objeto jeje :)

Comment: Mañana editare la pregunta para agregar ese caso

Comment: @AndreaJimenez edité la respuesta y le agregué el caso que me preguntabas. Espero que te sirva. Si te fue de utilidad, marca la respuesta como útil dandole en la felcha de arriba